# import statement fails for one module

Tags: python

Ok I found the problem, it was an environmental issue, I had the same modules (minus options.py) on the sys.path and it was importing from there instead.  Thanks everyone for your help.

I have a series of import statements, the last of which will not work. Any idea why? options.py is sitting in the same directory as everything else.

```
from snipplets.main import MainHandler
from snipplets.createnew import CreateNewHandler
from snipplets.db import DbSnipplet
from snipplets.highlight import HighLighter
from snipplets.options import Options
```

ImportError: No module named options

my __init__.py file in the snipplets directory is blank.

Comment: Post options.py.  You haven't given enough information for us to help.

Comment: Nothing special about it: http://github.com/woodenbrick/snipplets/blob/2c13a6de0ae5c6cb752bbc37e2620e823e498c97/snipplets/options.py

Comment: dev and master branch conflicting?

Comment: You need to supply some more context. I downloaded the code, but all of the imports above worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I might try restarting my computer, if that fixes it, i'm going to punch it, HARD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one of your other imports redefined `snipplets` with an assignment statement.  Or one of your other modules changed `sys.path`.

---

**Edit**

"so the flow goes like this: add snipplets packages to path import..."

No.

Do not modify `sys.path` -- that way lies problems.  Modifying `site.path` leads to ambiguity about what is -- or is not -- on the path, and what order they are in.

The simplest, most reliable, most obvious, most controllable things to do are the following.  Pick exactly one.

- Define `PYTHONPATH` (once, external to your program).  A single, simple environment variable that is nearly identical to installation on site-packages.
- Install your package in site-packages.

Comment: so the flow goes like this:
add snipplets packages to path
import snipplets modules
I tried moving the options import above everything else, but no change.

Comment: It would be my plan to add it to site-packages when distributed, but It's still under development.  Why would it be bad to modify sys.path?

Answer (score 2):

your [master branch](http://github.com/woodenbrick/snipplets/tree/68e40dcfa1195cc63d4e1155b8353bb1aa1f8797/snipplets) doesn't have `options.py`. could it be that you dev and master branches are conflicting?

[if this is your actual code](http://github.com/woodenbrick/snipplets/blob/2c13a6de0ae5c6cb752bbc37e2620e823e498c97/bin/snipplets) then you have `option` variable at line 21.

Comment: No i'm just using the dev branch currently, master hasn't been updated.

Comment: nice catch, its poor naming, but that's not the problem.

Comment: i've tried your code and had no problems with import. I'm still convinced that it's a clash of two branches.

Comment: Are you running from the dev branch?  I tried a fresh version on my machine, still has the same problem.  Perhaps its something on my machine only.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work?

```
import snipplets.options.Options
```

If so, one of your other snipplets files probably sets a global variable named options.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on windows?  You might want to try defining an `__`all`__` list in your `__`init`__`.py file like noted [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).  It shouldn't make a difference unless you're importing *, but I've seen modules not import unless they were defined there.

Secondly, you might try setting up a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  Using a lot of site-wide python packages can lead to these kinds of things.

Lastly, make sure the permissions of options are set correctly.  I've spent hours trying to figure these things out only to find out it was an issue of me not having permission to import it.

Comment: I'm on linux, so your first point doesn't apply.
I'll take a look at the virtualenv